# what's a authorization header? How is it used. How is it differrent from using login custom coding

Tags: jsp, tomcat, http-headers, authorization

Just found that there is a request header authorization. Want to know what is the use of this header. How is it used in the context of jsp tomcat servlet enviornment. How is it different from a normal login module, where user enters username password in a simple jsp page. How a page passes authorization header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of [HTTP *Basic* authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). This is the most basic way of authentication. When you enter such a website, you will be provided a 90's-style login popup (which look like a Javascript alert) where you can enter the credentials. In case of a Java EE servletcontainer, you can manage the logins and roles by container managed security. This is described in Java EE tutorial as well, starting in the chapter [*Defining Security Requirements*](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html#bncbn).

Needless to say that *Form based* authentication provides you more design freedom. You can just create a nice-looking HTML page with a `<form>` and let it submit to `j_security_check`. This is described in the same tutorial as well.